# Commando iptables and Ubuntu Linaro Desktop Distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian

I have a Raspberry machine, with "Raspbian" Linux Distro. I have setuped a little web server and I had no problems.

Now, I have a Cu-Box I machine, with "Ubuntu Linaro Desktop" Linux Distro. But, unfortunately I have an error by executing the following commando, when I am trying to redirect all requests from port 80 to port 8080 (simple forwarding). The commando is as follows :

```
$: sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

So, by the Raspbian Distro and by all another distros I have NO problem with this commando. But in the "Ubuntu Linaro Desktop" Distro, the OS says to me that the table "nat" does not exists, and maybe that I must recompile and upgrade my kernel - for me is that not the best solution.

However, please guys, can you tell me how can I avoid this commando and use another one instead.

Comment: Which version of Linaro are you running? That issue was known and fixed a couple of years ago, if my memory serves me well.

Comment: The version is as follows:
login as: linaro
linaro@89.215.43.108's password:
Welcome to Linaro 11.10 (development branch) (GNU/Linux 3.0.35-gbe699c6-dirty armv7l)

Comment: The distribution comes special as Linux for Cu Box-i v2. The image name is :ubuntu-oneiric-freescale.img which serve the above linaro distro, but i think is special for ARMv7 archit. I have tried to upgrade ot 12.04 LTS, after 3 hours upgrade, i have received a error message. Maybe this info can help you to answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: No, cannot be done. You can read here, https://bugs.launchpad.net/linaro-ubuntu/+bug/912319, the bug report. It affects Linaro 12.01 and earlier, kernel *Linux linaro-developer 3.1.1-5-linaro-lt-omap #5~lt~ci~20111218011838+020210-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 19 05: armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux*, which is later than yours.

Comment: Thanks Marius, i agree, that is very big trouble for people, who want just to redirect the 80- port. It is unbelievable ...

Comment: If all you wish is to redirect port 80, I can tell you how to do this without iptables. To where would you like to redirect port 80?

Comment: Thanks Marius - i use a Apache Tomcat and want to redirect all request comming for port 80 to port 8080, which is the default port for the Apache. Thanka a lot Marius in advance.

Comment: Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need need is to redirect port 80, then you can do it as follows:

```
  mkfifo my_pipe
  nc -l 80 0<my_pipe | nc remote_host 80 1>my_pipe
```

if you want to redirect it to another pc, or

```
  mkfifo my_pipe
  nc -l 80 0<my_pipe | nc loclhost 10000 1>my_pipe
```

if you want to redirect it to port 10000 of your own pc.

Edit:

if you want this to go on indefinitely, just add the **-k** option to the first instance of *nc*.

Comment: Yes, Marius,
it works but only for the first request. That's means, i put the commando, the bash is waiting, i make the request, the commando fills it up and works, and after that the bash waits for the next commando line - this means the redirect comes just one time. When i put the commando again, it works but just for the first browser request. So my question is - how can i make your commando permanent!!!  For every request, which comes from another machine (browsers ..). Thanks.

Comment: @user3157099 Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks, Marius, it works with the "-k" options. I think i that solves my problem.
Any idea where is the best place by ubuntu linaro, without desktop (startX), to place this commando so that it starts automatic by reboot ?

Comment: @user3157099 If it works, you should accept and upvote my answer, thank you.

Comment: @user3157099 A safe place is /etc/rc.local